# How to properly use metapost in plain LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, metapost

I'm trying to run some `metapost` code inside a plain `LuaTeX` file, but I don't know how to properly use it. In my example the text compiles fine, however the `metapost` code returns an error. How do I properly compile a `metapost` drawing with plain `LuaTeX`?

```
Testing metapost

\directlua{mp = mplib.new({
    beginfig(1);
        u=1cm;draw (2u,2u)--(0,0)--(0,3u)--(3u,0)--(0,0);
        pickup pencircle scaled 4pt;
        for i=0 upto 2:
            for j=0 upto 2:
                drawdot (i*u,j*u);
            endfor
        endfor
    endfig;
})}

\bye
```

Footnote: I don't want to build it with `ConTeXt`.

Comment: Why not use `luamplib`?

Comment: How do I use `luamplib` with plain `LuaTeX` @HenriMenke ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to make drawings, I recommend that you keep your hands off of the internal `mplib` module.  It is much simpler to use `luamplib` instead.

```
\input luamplib.sty

Testing metapost

\mplibcode
beginfig(1);
    u=1cm;draw (2u,2u)--(0,0)--(0,3u)--(3u,0)--(0,0);
    pickup pencircle scaled 4pt;
    for i=0 upto 2:
        for j=0 upto 2:
            drawdot (i*u,j*u);
        endfor
    endfor
endfig;
\endmplibcode

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\fontfam[Termes]
\load[minim-mp] % MetaPost

We are working on MetaPost
\directmetapost{
beginfig(1);
path p ;
p := fullcircle scaled 1cm ;
draw p scaled 2 withpen pencircle withcolor .8 green;
endfig;
}

\bye
```

Comment: This is not plain TeX. Can you please add some more details?

Comment: see more detail at https://petr.olsak.net/optex/